# Map existing folder to TFS without getting latest version

Tags: tfs, version-control

My TFS server is in internet. I don't want to get the source from server. Because it may take along time. Instead, I want to map an up-to-date source from my hard disk to TFS without getting the latest version. How can I bind my sources to TFS?

Comment: So do you want to override the server files with your files?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk No. I don't want to get the latest version forcedly and my files be valid, without getting from server. I know my files are in the latest version. But when I try to get latest version, TFS gets them all again from server.

Comment: If youur files are up-to-date TFS should know if and not download all again.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk And it's my opinion. But it's not what's gonna be happened. TFS gets them all 